# How can I make a copy of a string that is not an alias, but a copy of all the characters that make up the string?

Tags: java, string

I would like to make a copy of a string and then have the ability to make changes to the copy without changing the whole string. I tried using 
`String strTemplateTemp=new String(strTemplate);` instead of
`String strTemplateTemp=strTemplate;` I also tried using `clone` but got an error saying the clone method was not visible: `String strTemplateTemp=strTemplate.clone();`

My code

```
DefaultListModel<String> getAllMacrows()
{
    DefaultListModel<String> rows= new DefaultListModel<String>();
    int pes=0;
    int nameStart;
    int parEnd;     
    String row;
    String strTemplateTemp=new String(strTemplate);

    strTemplateTemp=strTemplateTemp.replace("\n"," ");
    // now both strTemplateTemp and  strTemplate have chnaged
    // want just strTemplateTemp to chnage
```

Comment: I think you might have tagged the wrong language. I think it's Java you need help with, not JavaScript.

Comment: `java` !== `javascript`. And I can't believe I had to add this comment to a question that *didn't* have the `java` tag in the beginning.

Comment: In Java, Strings are immutable. You can't change the original String, so the premise of this question is wrong.

Comment: *"have the abilty to make changes"* Java Strings are immutable, so you can't ever do that. I think you're looking for [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java `String` instances are *immutable*, so it is not possible to change the string (i.e., have a side effect). The statement:

```
 strTemplateTemp=strTemplateTemp.replace("\n"," ");
```

Creates a new string and assigns a reference to the new string to the variable `strTemplateTemp`.

> Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created. String buffers support mutable strings. Because String objects are immutable they can be shared. [java.lang.String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607990/how-should-i-copy-strings-in-java) for details.